# PHP Server-local Variable?

Tags: php

Short and sweet, I need to have a variable NOT be unset after a page has finished loading. I've used a file to store the value, and I've used a MySQL table with 1 record, and updated/read from that, but I want something cleaner and simpler. Any ideas?

Some people misunderstood the question, so here's an example. At the top of my page, I would have some code such as:

```
$_PERMANENT['hits']+=1;
print 'Hits: '.$_PERMANENT['hits'];
```

Note that this works across multiple clients, so it's not $_SESSION.

Comment: Wish you would have made that more clear in the first place. For this, a MySQL query like 'UPDATE hit SET counter = counter + 1' is very appropriate. However, that's not a lot of information. Recommend installing an approach like Google Analytics, instead.

Comment: It's not for hitcounts, it's for whatever. The MySQL approach I've tried, as I said, but then you have to connect to it, select a DB, run a whole query, get the output.. It's a lot of functions. I'm ideally aiming for some sort of "permament" superglobal array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer: [apc_store](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) et al

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), that's exactly what it's for. This either requires the user's browser has cookies on, or that you format links to maintain the session id.

At the start of your pages, use `session_start()` - only do this once, and it must be before content is written as it needs access to the header area.

`session_register()` is deprecated, so just do a `$_SESSION['key'] = $value;` and the next page load within that session will have access to the value via: `$value = $_SESSION['key'];`

Comment: Search for perhaps a more applicable [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848455/php-application-global-settings), there's lots of existing answers that will help.